# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'which' of undefined. I get the same issue when I use key

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to do access a certain element in the array when a certain key is pressed. I can I could either use event.which or event.key according to w3 but I would have to adjust what x was comparing to. But regardless I still get the same Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'which' of undefined or Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'key' of undefined

```
var i = 0; // Start point
var pages_arr = []; // Pages array

pages_arr[0] = "JS_CSS_HTML_HW_home_page.html";
pages_arr[1] = "JS_CSS_HTML_HW_courses_page.html";
pages_arr[2] = "JS_CSS_HTML_HW_projects_page.html";
pages_arr[3] = "JS_CSS_HTML_HW_hobbies_page.html";
pages_arr[4] = "JS_CSS_HTML_HW_friends_page.html";

function keyTabChange(event){

var x = event.which;
// Unicode for Up = 38
// Unicode for Right  = 39
// Unicode for left = 37
// Uniceode for downn = 40
//var curr_window = window.location.href;   // Get URL of string of webpage location

//i = pages_arr.indexOf(curr_window);   // Get the index of that location in the array of pages

if (x == 38 || x == 37){    // Previous tab 
    if (i == 0){
        i = pages_arr.length - 1;   // If index at first element in array go to end of the array
    }
    else{
        --i;    // All other cases go to previous tab
    }     

}
else if (x== 39 || x == 40){ // Next tab
    if (i==pages_arr.length - 1){
        i = 0;  // If index is at last element go to first element of array

    }
    else{
        ++i;    // All other cases go to next tab
    }

}
//window.location.assign(pages_arr[i]); // Load page of the URL
//document.write(pages_arr[i]);

document.getElementById("TestID").innerHTML = pages_arr[i];
```

}

document.addEventListener("keyup", keyTabChange(event));
**strong text**

Comment: `document.addEventListener("keyup", keyTabChange(event));` => `document.addEventListener("keyup", keyTabChange);`, see the linked question's answers for why.

Answer (score 0):

Because you misused the `addEventListener` method, instead of having

`document.addEventListener("keyup", keyTabChange(event));`

you need

`document.addEventListener("keyup", keyTabChange);`

e.g. Pass the NAME of the function instead of the function CALL.

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_ondrop_addeventlistener